# Typescript - Omit props with specific types

Tags: typescript

Let's say we have a type:

```
type myType = {
    a: string,
    b: boolean,
    c: () => void
}
```

To get a type, for example, with only the `a` and `b` properties, I do the following:

```
type ExcludeType<T, R> = { [K in keyof T as T[K] extends R ? never : K]: T[K] }
type ABType = ExcludeType<myType, Function>
```

But this is inconvenient if you need to exclude multiple types.

```
type AType = ExcludeType<ExcludeType<myType, Function>, boolean>
```

So how can you write a conditional type that, for example, recursively iterates over all types that need to be excluded? It would be great if I could use it like below:

```
type AType = ExcludeTypes<myType, Function | boolean >;
```

**EDIT:**

Not sure why I asked this question(perhaps, it was a busy day), but it works with no extra effort. So, if you want to exclude several types, you can use `ExcludeType` with `union` like shown as above.

Comment: I don't see what the problem is. `ExcludeTypes<myType, Function | boolean>` becomes `{a: string}`: https://tsplay.dev/mpDjbm

Comment: @cherryblossom is right. What you wish would work does, indeed, just work.

Comment: It was a busy day! :) Thanks guys